# How to compare two persian date to find out which one is greater?

Tags: c#, lambda, persian-calendar

I want to compare two persian dates to find out which one is greater, I use this function :

```
public static List<MatchDrawHistory> GetAllMatchDrawHistory(string startDate, string endDate) 
{
    using (var db= new ReceiveSendEntitiesV5())
    {
        var matchDrawList = db.MatchDrawHistories.Where(x => String.CompareOrdinal(x.DrawStartDate,startDate)>=0 && String.CompareOrdinal(x.DrawEndDate , endDate) <=0).ToList();
        return matchDrawList;
    }
}
```

but it does not work, how can I do it?

EDIT:  `DrawStartDate` and `DrawStartDate` are `nvarchar(20)` in `DataBase`, and these are persian date  not gregorian date

Comment: Edited my answer to include details of the PersianCalendar class.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to convert your `string` date to `DateTime`. Assuming your string date is as *yyyy/MM/dd*, the conversion function can be as follow:

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string date)
{
    var pc = new PersianCalendar();
    string[] arrDate = date.Split("/");

     return pc.ToDateTime(Int32.Parse(arrDate[0]), Int32.Parse(arrDate[1]), 
        Int32.Parse(arrDate[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now you can use the following method to compare two dates:

```
private static bool Compare(DateTime firstDate, DateTime secondDate)
{
    return firstDate >= secondDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to store the dates as strings.  I presume the dates in your class are strings, so I would pass in a DateTime, and use something like the following:

```
var matchDrawList = db.MatchDrawHistories.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.DrawStartDate) >= startDate && DateTime.Parse(x.DrawEndDate) <= endDate).ToList();
```

If you're not sure that the string will resolve to a date correctly, you could create a function to wrap a `TryParse`, depending on your business logic this may be preferable, as presumably you still want other results if one has an invalid date.

```
static bool CheckDateGreater(string date1, string date2)
{
    DateTime dt1;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(date1, out dt) return false;

    DateTime dt2;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(date2, out dt) return false;

    return (dt1 >= dt2);
}
```

Then call:

```
var matchDrawList = db.MatchDrawHistories.Where(x => CheckDateGreater(x.DrawStartDate, startDate) && CheckDateGreater(endDate, x.DrawEndDate).ToList();
```

EDIT:

Just seen your comment about Persian date.  You need to use the [PersianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  That should return you a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime` for the comparison rather than `string`

```
var start = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
var end = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
...
db.MatchDrawHistories.Where(x => x.DrawStartDate >= start && x.DrawEndDate <= end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CompareTo method like below code:
if(endDate.CompareTo(startDate) < 0)
//startDate is greater